# MudTextField How do I prevent autofill?

Tags: mudblazor, mudtextfield

I have two MudTextFields that are getting autofilled from the browser password store.  Neither of the fields have anything to do with login.  How can I prevent ANY form of autofill for both of them?

This is what I get:
[image]

Here are the field definitions:

```
<MudTextField @bind-Value="CompanyName" Label="Firma" Variant="Variant.Text"></MudTextField>
<MudTextField @bind-Value="EncryptionSecret" Label="Krypteringsnøkkel" Variant="Variant.Text" InputType="InputType.Password" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

`autocomplete="new-email"` and `autocomplete="new-password"` both work.

```
<MudTextField @bind-Value="CompanyName" Label="Firma" Variant="Variant.Text" autocomplete="new-email"></MudTextField>

<MudTextField @bind-Value="EncryptionSecret" Label="Krypteringsnøkkel" Variant="Variant.Text" InputType="InputType.Password" autocomplete="new-password" />
```